# How to use a turtle superclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, superclass, turtle-graphics

I'm making a solar system replica using turtle graphics.
I want to make a star and a planet that both inherit from the same turtle superclass "solar_element", but I'm having problems.

I can make the star and planet using two different turtle classes with no problems:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class star(Turtle):
   def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
    Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
    self.Name = Name
    self.Radius = Radius
    self.Mass = Mass
    self.color(Colour)
    self.shapesize(self.Radius/50)

class planet(Turtle):
 def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour, Dist, velX, velY):
    Turtle.__init__(self, shape= "circle")
    self.Name = Name
    self.Radius = Radius
    self.Mass = Mass
    self.color(Colour)
    self.Dist = Dist
    self.velX = velX
    self.velY = velY
    self.x_pos = sun.Radius + self.Dist + self.Radius
    self.y_pos = 0
    self.shapesize(self.Radius/50)

sun = star('myStar', 500.0, 15000.0, "yellow");
earth = planet('P1', 150.0, 1000.0, "green", 0.25, 0.5, 2.0);
```

But when I try to make them inherit from one superclass, like this:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class solar_element(Turtle):
 def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
    self.Name = Name
    self.Radius = Radius
    self.Mass = Mass
    self.Colour = Colour
    self.color(self.Colour)
    self.shapesize(self.Radius/50)

class star(solar_element):
 def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
    solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
    Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")

class planet(solar_element):
 def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour, Dist, velX, velY):
    solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
    Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
    self.Dist = Dist
    self.velX = velX
    self.velY = velY
    self.x_pos = sun.Radius + self.Dist + self.Radius
    self.y_pos = 0

sun = star('myStar', 500.0, 15000.0, "yellow");
earth = planet('P1', 150.0, 1000.0, "green", 0.25, 0.5, 2.0);
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kev\Dropbox\OOP\testing_classes.py", line 62, in <module>
    sun = star('myStar', 500.0, 15000.0, "yellow");
  File "C:\Users\Kev\Dropbox\OOP\testing_classes.py", line 47, in __init__
    solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
  File "C:\Users\Kev\Dropbox\OOP\testing_classes.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.color(self.Colour)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2208, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\turtle.py", line 2688, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
AttributeError: 'star' object has no attribute 'screen'
```

I realize I could just stick with two classes but I want to use a superclass, as I'm still trying to learn python.

Comment: Post the `Turtle` class please.

Comment: @Remolten What do you mean? I don't have anything else to post, the first part of the code works try it.

Comment: My bad, forgot that python has a turtle module.

Comment: Suggestion for future visitors: [don't subclass Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441331/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-python-that-is-inherited-from-turtle-module/71003069#71003069). It causes more trouble than its worth. Composition is the safest and clearest way to use Turtle along with custom classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call `Turtle` constructor before calling `solar_element` constructor, in your `star` and `planet` classes.

So change  your code in `__init__` method of `star` class to :

```
Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
```

And change   your code in `__init__` method of `planet` class to :

```
Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
```

At first, we usually need to call constructor of a base class in `__init__` method when we want to override that.
In fact, we call it at first when we want to to use a part of a class in `__init__` method, here for example a `color` method,
that this method needs some preparation is performed for that before anyone can use it.
here for example `screen` of `color` method of `Turtle` needs to set before we can use this method.

Some refactoring with your code:

- The class names should normally use the CapWords convention
- You don't need `;` at the end of lines.
- The variable names should be lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
- Using `super(YourInheritedClass, self).__init__()` instead of
  `ParentClass.__init__(self)`

Code:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class SolarElement(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, name, radius, mass, colour, shape='circle'):
        # or Turtle.__init__(self, shape=shape)
        super(SolarElement, self).__init__(shape=shape)
        self.name = name
        self.radius = radius
        self.mass = mass
        self.colour = colour
        self.color(self.colour)
        self.shapesize(self.radius / 50)


class Star(SolarElement):
    def __init__(self, name, radius, mass, colour,
                 shape='circle'):
        SolarElement.__init__(self, name, radius, mass, colour,
                              shape=shape)


class Planet(SolarElement):
    def __init__(self, name, radius, mass, colour, dist, vel_x, vel_y,
                 shape='circle'):
        SolarElement.__init__(self, name, radius, mass, colour,
                              shape=shape)
        self.dist = dist
        self.vel_x = vel_x
        self.vel_y = vel_y
        self.x_pos = sun.radius + self.dist + self.radius
        self.y_pos = 0

sun = Star('myStar', 500.0, 15000.0, "yellow")
earth = Planet('P1', 150.0, 1000.0, "green", 0.25, 0.5, 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that the call `self.color(self.Colour)` in `solar_object.__init__` doesn't work correctly if the `Turtle` class's `__init__` method has not yet been called.

Your current code calls `Turtle.__init__` *after* it calls `solar_object.__init__`, so a first swag at a fix would be to simply call it first.

However, I'd suggest changing things a bit more, and have `solar_object.__init__` do the call to `Turtle.__init__`. This way, you don't need for every later subclass to also get the initializers in the right order.

```
class solar_element(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape="circle")
        # ...
```

I'd further suggest that you learn about the `super` function, which Python provides as a way of calling methods on your superclasses without naming them specifically. Rather than `Turtle.__init__`, you'd call `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're deriving a subclass of `Turtle`, you need to initialize the base class in your subclass`__init__()`methods:

```
from turtle import Turtle

class solar_element(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
        super(solar_element, self).__init__()
        self.Name = Name
        self.Radius = Radius
        self.Mass = Mass
        self.Colour = Colour
        self.color(self.Colour)
        self.shapesize(self.Radius/50)

class star(solar_element):
    def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour):
        solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")

class planet(solar_element):
    def __init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour, Dist, velX, velY):
        super(solar_element, self).__init__()
        solar_element.__init__(self, Name, Radius, Mass, Colour)
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape = "circle")
        self.Dist = Dist
        self.velX = velX
        self.velY = velY
        self.x_pos = sun.Radius + self.Dist + self.Radius
        self.y_pos = 0

sun = star('myStar', 500.0, 15000.0, "yellow")
earth = planet('P1', 150.0, 1000.0, "green", 0.25, 0.5, 2.0)
```