# Why is there a second Turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am learning turtle graphics in python and for some reason there is a second turtle on the screen and I haven't even created a second turtle. How can I get rid of the second turtle?

```
import turtle
s = turtle.getscreen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(4):
    t.fd(100)
    t.rt(90)
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Related: [Third Clone Of The Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559538/third-clone-of-the-turtle/75560168#75559538). `turtle.getscreen` is a global function that creates the singleton functional turtle if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second turtle at the starting location appears because of the line `s = turtle.getscreen()`.

This line is not needed (you do not use `s`), and if you remove it this turtle disappears but the rest of the code seems to work as before.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks! I was following a guide on realpython.com and I was told that to open the turtle screen I need to write s = turtle.getscreen()

Answer (score 1):

The turtle library exposes two interfaces, a *functional* one (for beginners) and an *object-oriented* one. You got that extra turtle because you mixed the two interfaces (and @mkrieger1's solution doesn't fix that completely).

I always recommend an `import` like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```

This gives you access to the object-oriented interface and blocks the functional one. Mixing the two leads to all sorts of bugs and artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

To combine the answer from mkrieger1 and cdlane, you could *replace*

```
s = turtle.getscreen()
```

with

```
s = turtle.Screen()
```

You've still got a variable holding the screen (in case you should ever need it), and it doesn't generate that extra turtle in the center.