# Third Clone Of The Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I made this program, when trying to make a chase game, but I stumbled along something really strange. I created a clone of the turtle, but at the middle of the map a third one appeared.

Does anybody know what causes this?

```py
import turtle

sc = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
c = turtle.clone()
c.penup
t.penup
c.goto(100,100)

def turnleft():
    t.left(30)

def turnright():
    t.right(30)

while True:
    t.forward(2)
    c.forward(2)
    sc.onkey(turnleft, "Left")
    sc.onkey(turnright, "Right")
    sc.listen()
```

Comment: This is not necessarily your problem, but FYI, you are not calling `c.penup` or `t.penup`. You need to replace them with `c.penup()` and `t.penup()`.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem with the third turtle appearing in the middle of the map.

Comment: I know, hence why I said `This is not necessarily your problem` and that it was an FYI.

Comment: Sorry if it seems obvious, but what is FYI? (I am not that great of a computer guy)

Comment: FYI means "for your information" :-P

Comment: How many turtles do you get if you clone the cloned turtle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question. I'm able to reproduce the behavior: if you only make one turtle, `print(len(turtle.turtles()))` gives 1 as expected, but after cloning once, there's suddenly 3. Here's a minimal example:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
print(len(turtle.turtles())) # => 1, no problem
c = turtle.clone()
print(len(turtle.turtles())) # => 3 !!?
```

The problem is calling `.clone()` on `turtle` (the module) rather than on the turtle instance you want to clone:

```py
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
c = t.clone()
print(len(turtle.turtles())) # => 2 as expected
```

This is a classic [turtle gotcha](https://gist.github.com/ggorlen/f46857bd0057ca919b97d5569f6ec641): mistaking the functional interface for the object-oriented interface. When you call `turtle.clone()`, it's a functional call, so the module creates its singleton non-OOP turtle, then clones it and returns the clone which you store in `c`.

The inimitable [cdlane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771269/cdlane) [advocates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62296811/6243352) for the following import:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
```

which makes it hard to mess things up.

---

If you're curious about the CPython turtle internals that cause the behavior to occur, here's the code (from [Lib/turtle.py#L3956](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/81bf10e4f20a0f6d36b67085eefafdf7ebb97c33/Lib/turtle.py#L3956)):

```py
## The following mechanism makes all methods of RawTurtle and Turtle available
## as functions. So we can enhance, change, add, delete methods to these
## classes and do not need to change anything here.

__func_body = """\
def {name}{paramslist}:
    if {obj} is None:
        if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
            TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
            raise Terminator
        {obj} = {init}
    try:
        return {obj}.{name}{argslist}
    except TK.TclError:
        if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
            TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
            raise Terminator
        raise
"""

def _make_global_funcs(functions, cls, obj, init, docrevise):
    for methodname in functions:
        method = getattr(cls, methodname)
        pl1, pl2 = getmethparlist(method)
        if pl1 == "":
            print(">>>>>>", pl1, pl2)
            continue
        defstr = __func_body.format(obj=obj, init=init, name=methodname,
                                    paramslist=pl1, argslist=pl2)
        exec(defstr, globals())
        globals()[methodname].__doc__ = docrevise(method.__doc__)

_make_global_funcs(_tg_screen_functions, _Screen,
                   'Turtle._screen', 'Screen()', _screen_docrevise)
_make_global_funcs(_tg_turtle_functions, Turtle,
                   'Turtle._pen', 'Turtle()', _turtle_docrevise)
```

This takes all of the turtle `Screen()` and `Turtle()` methods and wires them into the module's globals, so `turtle.Turtle().clone` is set to `turtle.clone`. As part of this rewiring, `__func_body` adds a bit of boilerplate to every call which checks to see whether `Turtle._pen` or `Turtle._screen` exist already, and creates them if they don't.

---

Unrelated, but you need to call `pendown()` with parentheses if you want it to do anything. Also, it's a good idea to set event listeners before the loop rather than inside of it, or just remove that entirely since it's not relevant to the question.