# Why is there a little arrow in the middle of the screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I hide all turtles that are supposed to be hidden.  I am wondering why there is always a little arrow in the middle of the screen (see screen shot below code).

```
import time
from turtle import Screen
from player import Player
from car_manager import CarManager
from scoreboard import Scoreboard

play = Player()
scoreboard = Scoreboard()
car_manager = CarManager()
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(play.turtle_move_up, "Up")

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()
    car_manager.create_car()
    car_manager.car_move()

    if play.is_at_cross_line():
        scoreboard.score_increase()
        car_manager.speed_up()
        play.move_to_starting_point()

    for car in car_manager.car_list:
        if car.distance(play) < 20:
            scoreboard.game_over()
            game_is_on = False

screen.exitonclick()


# classes 

from turtle import Turtle

FONT = ("Courier", 24, "normal")

class Scoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hideturtle()
        self.penup()
        self.level = 1
        self.score_update()

    def score_update(self):
        self.clear()
        self.goto(-260, 260)
        self.write(f"Level:{self.level}", align="left", font=FONT)

    def score_increase(self):
        self.level += 1
        self.score_update()

    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.write("Game Over", align='center', font=FONT)



from turtle import Turtle

STARTING_POSITION = (0, -280)
MOVE_DISTANCE = 10
FINISH_LINE_Y = 280


class Player(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.speed = MOVE_DISTANCE
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.move_to_starting_point()

    def move_to_starting_point(self):
        self.goto(0, -280)
        self.setheading(90)

    def turtle_move_up(self):
        self.forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)

    def is_at_cross_line(self):
        if self.ycor() > 280:
            return True
        else:
            return False




from turtle import Turtle
import random

COLORS = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE = 5
MOVE_INCREMENT = 10


class CarManager(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.car_list = []
        self.speed = STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE

    def create_car(self):
        random_chance = random.randint(1,6)
        if random_chance == 1:
            new_car = Turtle("square")
            new_car.penup()
            new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
            new_car.color(random.choice(COLORS))
            new_car.goto(300, random.randint(-230, 230))
            self.car_list.append(new_car)

    def car_move(self):
        for car in self.car_list:
            car.backward(self.speed)

    def speed_up(self):
        self.speed += MOVE_INCREMENT
```

[image: Screen shot illustrating the problem]

How can I get rid of the annoying `>`-like arrow in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Don't subclass `Turtle` with `CarManager(Turtle)`, Just do `CarManager()` since you instance creates them with `Turtle("square")`.

Comment: @ggorlen, ...does it add anything of substance not covered in the prior questions linked by your (excellent) answer? (I'm asking because I _don't know_; there's too much here for it to be clear what is and isn't relevant to the actual problem without the kind of time and expertise you've put in).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good question--the reason this question is useful is that it combines confusion about the common "extra turtle" bug with inheritance. The two questions I've linked don't use subclassing at all. [Paddles on my Pong game do not move after pressing the keys on Python 3.11 Turtle Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76965474/paddles-on-my-pong-game-do-not-move-after-pressing-the-keys-on-python-3-11-turtl/) is pretty similar to this, but different enough to warrant a separate question--this one is a bit more subtle about inadvertently using both inheritance and composition.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for that context and analysis. I haven't cast a downvote to retract (and good practice is to vote on a standalone evaluation of merit, as opposed to trying to counteract others' votes)... but if the OP minifies this towards being a proper [mre] and pings me after having done so, I'll be glad to cast an upvote. :)

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to `import` anything more than once in the same file.

Comment: @tripleee OP has different files and just smushed them together into one code block. Otherwise `from car_manager import CarManager` would fail.

Comment: Oh, then, the question would be much improved by indicating the file names of each code snippet separately so that we don't have to guess. But of course with a [mre] you would not have multiple files in most scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot going on here. A very important concept in debugging is [*minimizing the problem*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's too much code here to easily make sense of the issue. One way to resolve this is to remove pieces of code until the problem disappears (either piece by piece, or in a [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) manner), then re-add the last bit in as a means of isolating the problem.

Another approach is to start from scratch, adding code until the problem appears.

Following the code removal strategy, I was able to minimize the failing example. The problem is still there, but with less noise and distractions, making it easier to understand the situation. In the future, I recommend doing this on your own before posting, taking care not to remove too much context that may be relevant. If you minimize sufficiently, you usually won't have to ask a question and you can fix the bug yourself.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


class CarManager(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def create_car(self):
        new_car = Turtle("square")
        new_car.penup()
        new_car.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=2)
        new_car.goto(100, 100)


screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)
cm = CarManager()
cm.create_car()
screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

This is minimal because removing `CarManager` makes the problem disappear. `CarManager` is a `Turtle` (inheritance), yet it's also producing car turtles ("has-a", composition, `new_car = Turtle("square")` which are stored in a list). In this case, it doesn't make sense for `CarManager` to be a turtle: it's just a container class with methods to generate turtles, but `self` is never used as a turtle to move or draw things as done with the other classes. Subclassing `Turtle` creates a turtle (that's the one you see in the center of the screen), but if you don't use it for anything, it'll sit idle in the middle of the screen.

The easiest fix is:

```py
class CarManager:  # remove subclass
    def __init__(self):
        ...  # remove super()

# rest is the same
```

The fundamental issue, though, is that [subclassing turtle is an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352). By mixing your class into turtle, a great deal of confusion can occur due to the 120+ methods it inherits, difficulty managing the auto-instantiated turtles (as was the case here), and confusing error messages referring to deep turtle or tkinter internals when an error occurs.

Instead, always use composition ("has-a") when working with Turtle. This will reduce confusion and footguns. You can think of it as "A Scoreboard has a turtle pen it can use to draw" rather than "A Scoreboard is a turtle that draws".

For example:

```py
class Scoreboard:  # no inheritance!
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen = pen = Turtle()  # Scoreboard "has-a" turtle
        pen.hideturtle()
        pen.penup()
        pen.score_update()
        self.level = 1

    def score_update(self):
        self.pen.clear()
        self.pen.goto(-260, 260)
        self.pen.write(f"Level:{self.level}", align="left", font=FONT)
```

Note that `self.level` is not on the turtle, it's on the Scoreboard. Given that turtles have hundreds of properties, it's very easy to overwrite something and wind up in a situation where turtle reports that its own methods can't be called! (or worse, that it silently calls your method instead of turtle's, leading to subtle unexpected behavior that's hard to track down)

The only downside with composition is code verbosity, `self.turtle.goto(...)` instead of `self.goto(...)`. Although this extra property is good in that it clarifies ownership, it's a bit uglier to read and write. You can use `self.t` or `self.pen` if you don't mind a shorter variable, or unpack the turtle property with `turt = self.turtle` in each method, then use `turt.goto(...)` and so forth for the remainder of the method.

Also, avoid `while True:`. Instead, use `ontimer`, which lets turtle manage the event loop as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352).

Related:

- [Why is there a second Turtle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263467/why-is-there-a-second-turtle)
- [Third Clone Of The Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559538/third-clone-of-the-turtle/75560168#75559538)
- [Little black square in center of screen after each restart in turtle graphics pong game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310198/little-black-square-in-center-of-screen-after-each-restart-in-turtle-graphics-po/77461284#77461284)
- [Paddles on my Pong game do not move after pressing the keys on Python 3.11 Turtle Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76965474/paddles-on-my-pong-game-do-not-move-after-pressing-the-keys-on-python-3-11-turtl/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not inherently wrong to have a turtle car manager; so when we decide or enjoy the inheritance way of implementation :: we can try to make use of the superclass [constructor<s>(s)</s>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-implement-multiple-constructors).

A solution is to edit the initializer of your CarManager(Turtle) with the 3ed parameter = False.

```
class CarManager(Turtle):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("classic", 1000, False)
    self.car_list = []
    self.speed = STARTING_MOVE_DISTANCE
```

1st and 2ed parameters (shape: string, undobuffersize) of super's constructor are the default values found by printing a default instance turtle, or as listed in the "[How to configure Screen and Turtles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#how-to-configure-screen-and-turtles)" section.  The 3ed parameter of the Turtle() constructor is the relevant parameter, visible: bool.

Using Python 3.10 with your code, I had to put the top section below the classes and in a main method to run; made it to Lv5.