# How to restart a turtle graphics program back to the beginning?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, restart, python-turtle

Does anyone know how to restart the program like, for example, when a player reaches 5 points, after the text "Player a Wins" it will give a certain amount of time delay and then directly restart the game from 0 0. i created the score thingy but got stuck on restarting the program once it reaches 5 points?

I have imported `turtle` as game in the beginning.

```
if (scoreboard_a > 4):
    win.write("Player A WINS!", font=textfont2)
    game.reset()
elif (scoreboard_b > 4):
    win.write("Player B WINS!", font=textfont2)
    game.reset()
```

Comment: This could use a [mcve]. Related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748872), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930556), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804693), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310198), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933358)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `while` loop. Put *all* your code, expect maybe not the imports, into a `while` loop:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

while True:
    # All your game code here
    scoreboard_a = 0
    scoreboard_b = 0
    if (scoreboard_a > 4):
        win.write("Player A WINS!", font=textfont2)
    elif (scoreboard_b > 4):
        win.write("Player B WINS!", font=textfont2)
    sleep(2)
```

If your game is already in a `while` loop, use `break` when the game ends:

```
import turtle
from time import sleep

while True:
    # All your game code here
    scoreboard_a = 0
    scoreboard_b = 0
    while True:
        # All your game code here
        if (scoreboard_a > 4):
            win.write("Player A WINS!", font=textfont2)
            sleep(2)
            break
        elif (scoreboard_b > 4):
            win.write("Player B WINS!", font=textfont2)
            sleep(2)
            break
```

Comment: Here is a tip, using a while loop or `time.sleep()` is not a good idea for event-driven programs as it might make the GUI unresponsive. So, instead of `time.sleep()` use turtle's `ontimer()`

Answer (score 0):

You can restart the whole program like this:

```
import os
import sys
import time
time.sleep(2)
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

Or, you can reset the score(s) and other elements, like:

```
time.sleep(2)
# reset variables
```

Comment: thank you, helped me get the game to restart now @Programmer

Comment: Restarting the game by destroying and restarting the whole process is unnecessary, expensive, results in a poor user experience (the graphics window will close and reopen), error-prone and difficult to maintain. This can be done trivially inside one process with a simple control flow construct known as a _loop_. There's no need to get the operating system involved just to repeat some code.