# Python Turtle Race Restart Function

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics, restart, python-turtle

I just got done with my first Turtle Race and still had one assignment left, a restart function. I just cant get it to work as i want. The goal is, an output of a question: Restart? y or n, and that'll restart the race() function. I am really in need of your guys' help.

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint


Andi = Turtle("turtle")
Andi.color("red")
Andi.shape("turtle")
Andi.penup()
Andi.goto(-300,200)
Andi.pendown()

Dom = Turtle("turtle")
Dom.color("green")
Dom.shape("turtle")
Dom.penup()
Dom.setpos(-300,180)
Dom.pendown()

Pete = Turtle("turtle")
Pete.color("blue")
Pete.shape("turtle")
Pete.penup()
Pete.setpos(-300,160)
Pete.pendown()

Emir = Turtle("turtle")
Emir.color("yellow")
Emir.shape("turtle")
Emir.penup()
Emir.setpos(-300,220)
Emir.pendown()

windowcolor=Screen()
windowcolor.bgcolor("black")

turtles = [Emir, Pete, Dom, Andi]
def race():
    global turtles
    winner = False
    finishline = 300

    while not winner:
        for current_turtle in turtles:
            move = randint(0, 10)
            current_turtle.forward(move)
            xcor = current_turtle.xcor()
            if (xcor > finishline):
                winner = True
                current_turtle.forward(0)
                winner_color = current_turtle.color()
                print('The winner is', winner_color[1])
def restart():
    global turtles
    while race():
        turtle.clear()                
race ()
restart ()
while True:
    while True:
        answer = str(input("Restart? (y/n): "))
        if answer in ("y", "n"):
            break
        print("Invalid awnser")
    if answer == "y":
        race
    else:
        print("Shutting off")
        break

windowcolor.mainloop()

while True:
    windowcolor.update()
```

What am I doing wrong, in my restart() function?

Answer (score 1):

`turtles` is an array of `turtle`. You need to iterate the array and call every `clear()`.

```
def restart():
    global turtles
    while race():
        for turtle in turtles:
            turtle.clear()
```

Comment: `race()` returns `None` so the `while race():` seems like it'll never run more than once, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the turtle initialization code into a function, then call it whenever you want to reset the game:

```py
from random import randint
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def initialize():
    Screen().reset()
    Screen().bgcolor("black")
    andi.color("red")
    andi.shape("turtle")
    andi.penup()
    andi.goto(-300,200)
    andi.pendown()
    dom.color("green")
    dom.shape("turtle")
    dom.penup()
    dom.setpos(-300,180)
    dom.pendown()
    pete.color("blue")
    pete.shape("turtle")
    pete.penup()
    pete.setpos(-300,160)
    pete.pendown()
    emir.color("yellow")
    emir.shape("turtle")
    emir.penup()
    emir.setpos(-300,220)
    emir.pendown()
    

def race():
    winner = False
    finishline = 300

    while not winner:
        for current_turtle in turtles:
            move = randint(0, 10)
            current_turtle.forward(move)
            xcor = current_turtle.xcor()

            if xcor > finishline:
                winner = True
                current_turtle.forward(0)
                winner_color = current_turtle.color()
                print("The winner is", winner_color[1])


andi = Turtle()
dom = Turtle()
pete = Turtle()
emir = Turtle()
turtles = [emir, pete, dom, andi]

while True:
    initialize()
    race()

    while True:
        answer = input("Restart? (y/n): ")

        if answer in ("y", "n"):
            break

        print("Invalid awnser")

    if answer != "y":
        print("Shutting off")
        break
```

Other remarks:

- A line like `race` does nothing. You'll need to call that function: `race()`.
- Code after `while True:` will usually not run, unless you break out of the loop. By the time you break out of your main game loop, you've already printed "Shutting off" and so `mainloop` will just block up the screen. `mainloop` is infinite, so the `while True:` code after it is unreachable. Basically: be judicious with `while True:`; you'll usually only have one or two carefully-placed infinite loops in a turtle program like this.
- Consider using [`textinput()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.textinput) rather than `input()`. This way, the user is in the GUI the whole time.
- `windowcolor` is a strange variable name for a Screen. Just use `screen` or call the `Screen()` singleton getter every time you need it.
- `from turtle import *` is poor practice, polluting the global namespace with over a hundred turtle functions and creating confusion between the turtle functional and instance APIs. Always use `from turtle import Screen, Turtle`.
- `str(input())` is unnecessary--`input()` already returns a `str`.

---

Related questions:

- [How to restart a turtle graphics program back to the beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670853/how-to-restart-a-turtle-graphics-program-back-to-the-beginning)
- [How to reset the turtles and erase the text in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930556/how-to-reset-the-turtles-and-erase-the-text-in-turtle-graphics)
- [Re-Running a turtle program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66804693/re-running-a-turtle-program)
- [How to get my turtle program to restart based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933358/how-to-get-my-turtle-program-to-restart-based-on-user-input)