# Re-Running a turtle program

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have made a simple python program that creates randomly generated spirals using the turtle module. I am still pretty new at python and i was wondering how i could restart the program after the turtle is pretty far away from the center and the spiral is done. Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random

root = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()

colors = ["yellow", "gold", "orange", "red", "maroon", "violet", "magenta", "purple", "navy", "blue", "skyblue", "cyan", "turquoise", "lightgreen", "green", "darkgreen", "chocolate", "brown", "gray", "white"]

def spiral():
    endColors = [random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors)]
    angle = random.randint(60, 300)
    distance = turtle.distance(0, 0)
    
    print("Colors used are:", endColors)
    print("The turning angle is: ", angle, "deg")
    print("The distance is: ", distance)

    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    root.bgcolor("black")
    for i in range(2000):
        turtle.forward(i)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.color(endColors[i%3])
    root.mainloop()
spiral()
```

I have tried using the turtle.distance function in an if statement but it dident work.

Comment: Related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748872), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670853), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930556), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310198), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73933358)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by using a global flag variable and installing a turtle [timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) that calls a function that periodically checks to see whether a spiral has finished being drawn yet by looking at the variable — and if so, resets things and draws another one. In the code below the function that does that is named `check_status()`. I also added a short pause before the after each one is finished to allow it to remain visible long enough to be admired. `;¬)`

```
import random
import time
import turtle

root = turtle.Screen()
turtle = turtle.Turtle()

colors = ["yellow", "gold", "orange", "red", "maroon", "violet", "magenta",
          "purple", "navy", "blue", "skyblue", "cyan", "turquoise", "lightgreen",
          "green", "darkgreen", "chocolate", "brown", "gray", "white"]

MAX_DIST = 100
PAUSE = 2  # Secs


def spiral():
    global spiral_done
    spiral_done = False  # Global flag.

    endColors = [random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors), random.choice(colors)]
    angle = random.randint(60, 300)

    print("Colors used are:", endColors)
    print("The turning angle is: ", angle, "deg")

    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    root.bgcolor("black")
    for i in range(2000):
        turtle.forward(i)
        turtle.right(angle)
        turtle.color(endColors[i%3])
        if turtle.distance(0, 0) > MAX_DIST:  # Stop if far away.
            break

    time.sleep(PAUSE)
    spiral_done = True


def check_status():
    if spiral_done:
        root.reset()
        spiral()  # Draw another.
    root.ontimer(check_status, 250)  # Check every 1/4 second.


def main():
    global spiral_done
    spiral_done = True  # Initialize global flag.
    check_status()  # Start watching its value.
    spiral()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar to @martineau's except that I use `turtle.reset()` instead of `screen.reset()` and a simpler timing logic:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice, randint
from itertools import count

COLORS = [
    'yellow', 'gold', 'orange', 'red', 'maroon',
    'violet', 'magenta', 'purple', 'navy', 'blue',
    'skyblue', 'cyan', 'turquoise', 'lightgreen', 'green',
    'darkgreen', 'chocolate', 'brown', 'gray', 'white'
]

RADIUS = 100

def spiral():
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')

    triColors = [choice(COLORS), choice(COLORS), choice(COLORS)]
    angle = randint(60, 300)

    print("Colors used are:", triColors)
    print("The turning angle is: ", angle, "deg")
    print("The radius is: ", RADIUS)

    for distance in count():  # spiral forever until a specific radius is achieved
        turtle.pencolor(triColors[distance % 3])
        turtle.forward(distance)

        if turtle.distance(0, 0) > RADIUS:
            break

        turtle.right(angle)

    turtle.reset()
    screen.ontimer(spiral)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()

spiral()

screen.mainloop()
```