# How to make instances delete themselves?

Tags: class, instance, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am working on a quiz game with the `turtle` module and want 4 buttons each to work for the answers so I wanted to make the four buttons an instance from my button class and when all the questions were done I couldn't have them or the game would add more points and break it so I needed the buttons to commit suicide when the game was done and tried:

```
def goodbye(self):
    self.turtle.clear()
    self.turtle.hideturtle()
    del self.turtle
    del self
```

But the buttons were still clickable even though invisible and that was the exact thing I didn't want. I searched other questions related to this but none of them were relevant.

Also here is a trinket website in case you need more info about my code, but I didn't plan to share this with anyone, so I warn you it isn't polished https://trinket.io/python/f01a6c3bcc.

edit: someone in the comments section(@martineau) helped me with my button problem (: . So in my deleting method, I added self.turtle.onclick(None) to get my buttons not getting clicked the score wouldn't go up and my game wouldn't be broken. i hope this helps someone

```py
def goodbye(self):
    self.turtle.clear()
    self.turtle.hideturtle()
    self.turtle.onclick(None)
    del self.turtle
    del self
```

Comment: This should be asked as a question about your GUI toolkit, not about Python-the-language.

Comment: ...so, please re-tag and re-title. If `turtle` is the only GUI toolkit you're using, tag for that -- and do make sure the code _included in the question_ is a [mre] that can be run to see the problem when run without changes.

Comment: As long as some code somewhere still has a reference to an object, the object will continue to exist.  `del` only affects the ability of the current code to use it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what do you mean

Comment: @MarkRansom, ...and moreover, many GUI toolkits will have references internally to instantiated objects, so how to properly delete things in a way that the GUI will respect is a library-specific question.

Comment: @Gili, which specific statement are you asking me to clarify, and what was the precise ambiguity in that statement? "What do you mean" on its own just tells me to rewrite everything I said above, without telling me how to write it differently to fix whatever made it hard to understand.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just didn't understand your question I was expecting you to explain what you meant. I feel like you're getting offended by my inability to process what you said

Comment: Which _specific_ question don't you understand? I'm not angry or offended; I'm asking in good faith.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what's a GUI toolkit is what I wanted to understand in your comment "This should be asked as a question about your GUI toolkit, not about Python-the-language. –"

Comment: In this case, your GUI toolkit is `turtle`. (Other popular options include tkinter, pyqt, pygtk, etc).

Comment: ...so, while `turtle` isn't a GUI toolkit I've used, the thing that looks likely is that the `onclick` callback isn't being cleared -- thus, it constitutes a still-held reference to your button object (as MarkRansom discussed). Again, I've never used this one before, but `onclick(None)` looks from a quick glance at the manual like what might be the right direction to go in.

Comment: I fixed the onclick by binding the methods and what not (I just put self.turtle.onclick(self.click) and click was another method for my button) The onclick works if that's what you meant

Comment: You want to _stop_ the onclick from working when the button is deleted, though, right? If you try to delete the button, that doesn't magically deregister the handler; you need to deregister it (or make it do a check that fails before taking any action, should it still be registered) yourself.

Comment: ...mind, insofar as the code that's registering the handlers you want to destroy isn't currently included in the question, this question isn't currently on-topic here (links are fine, but they need to be additional/supplemental information -- the question should still be answerable, answers testable, and people who find the Q&A entry in the future able to learn from the questions and answers all taken together even if all the links break; the point of the [mre] guidelines in the Help Center is to try to ensure the above).

Comment: `onclick(None)` is the way to  remove existing bindings according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick). Please provide a [mre] in your question, off-site links to code are discouraged here because they can and often do disappear over time.

Comment: @martineau okay thanks I will try using onclick(None). I didn't want to paste the entire code into my problem because then it would be boring so I found the first website that came to me and pasted all the code that I wrote. I don't usually code on trinket for your information.

Comment: Please post your solution [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) rather than as an edit to the question. Thanks. Related: [How to fully delete a turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43972351/how-to-fully-delete-a-turtle), although it sounds like removing handlers is enough here (that doesn't actually delete the turtle though).