# Turtle Subclass "object has no attribute '_shown'"

Tags: python, python-turtle

New to Python here.
I am messing around with Turtle module, and when I try to create a Turtle type class the following way I get the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Buttons' object has no attribute '_shown'
```

My Python script:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

class Buttons(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, color, text):
        self.hideturtle()
        self.color(color)
        self.shape('square')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=7)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 0)
        self.stamp()
        self.color('white')
        self.goto(0, 0 - FONT_SIZE/2)
        self.write(text, align='center', font=FONT)


t1 = Buttons("green", "start")

while True:
    wn.update()
```

Comment: You failed to call the inherited `__init__()` method, so your subclass never received the initialization that would make it a functional Turtle.  `turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)` would be one way of writing this.

Comment: What @jasonharper is true. You can also do it using the slightly shorter `super().__init__()`.

Comment: @jasonharper, you should post this as an answer, IMHO.

Comment: I suggest [not subclassing Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441331/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-python-that-is-inherited-from-turtle-module/71003069#71003069) in the first place.