# Turtle OnKey() doesn't work despite all I've tried

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, listen

The Onkey() does'nt work though I've tried all I've come across. Please I really need help to fix this as soon as possible.
Here i'm trying to build a game with turtle. Breakout game to be precise.

```
class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = Turtle("square")
        self.player.shapesize(stretch_len=8, stretch_wid=1)
        self.player.penup()
        self.player.color("white")
        self.player.goto(0, -200)
        self.player.speed("fastest")

    def go_left(self):
        self.setheading(0)
        self.forward(10)
        # screen.update()

    def go_right(self):
        self.setheading(180)
        self.forward(30)
        # screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("BREAKOUT GAME")
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()
block = Block()
ball = Ball()

screen.update()
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(player.go_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(player.go_left, "Left")
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'm not a big fan of subclassing Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352), which practically guarantees confusion as to which methods you're invoking, as is the case here. I suggest using composition rather than inheritance.

The general debugging strategy is to minimize your problem systematically. If you add a `print("here")` in the `go_` methods, you'll see they're called just fine on the corresponding arrow key presses.

The next step is to determine if the screen is being updated. It's not, because `screen.update()` was commented out. This method is necessary whenever you use `turtle.tracer(0)` to disable the internal turtle loop. Bring these update calls back.

After making that adjustment, player movement still isn't functional. A quick inspection of the class shows that most of the logic involves `self.player = Turtle("square")`, which is the turtle you see on the screen. This class is actually using composition *and* inheritance, so `Player` both *is-a* turtle (`self`) and *has-a* turtle (`self.player`). Pick one or the other and use it throughout, preferably the *has-a* turtle (`self.player`).

Also, `self.player.speed("fastest")` is unnecessary since you disabled `tracer` and the player moves at different speeds in each direction.

Here's the fixed code:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = Turtle("square")
        self.player.shapesize(stretch_len=8, stretch_wid=1)
        self.player.penup()
        self.player.color("white")
        self.player.goto(0, -200)

    def go_left(self):
        self.player.setheading(0)
        self.player.forward(30)
        screen.update()

    def go_right(self):
        self.player.setheading(180)
        self.player.forward(30)
        screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("BREAKOUT GAME")
screen.tracer(0)

player = Player()
#block = Block()
#ball = Ball()

screen.update()
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(player.go_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(player.go_left, "Left")
screen.exitonclick()
```

Although this works, calling `screen.update()` in the event handlers is suboptimal. As you bring in more entities, you'll have to call this everywhere, and as we've seen, forgetting a call can lead to a bug. Once you're ready to implement continuous movement, I'd suggest using your own rendering/update loop that calls `screen.update` one time after updates have been applied to all entities. This allows you to press-and-hold keys to move the player padddle. See [How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967) for my suggested setup.