# Why tail of my snake is getting detach from its body

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Everything works properly after compiling this code up until the point where I try to extend my snake; however, when I do, the snake detaches from the body and the extend function fails, as shown in the picture below.
how can I attach the new segment to body so that it updates score and body of snake will increase its segment as well
[Snake body detach with body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBdsE.png**Main.py**)

```
  from turtle import Screen
    from food import Food
    from snakee import Snake
    from score import Score
    
    screen=Screen()
    screen.setup(600,600)
    screen.bgcolor("black")
    screen.title("Snake game")
    screen.tracer(0)
    
    snake=Snake()
    food=Food()
    score=Score()
    
    screen.listen()
    screen.onkey(snake.up,"Up")
    screen.onkey(snake.down,"Down")
    screen.onkey(snake.right,"Right")
    screen.onkey(snake.left,"Left")
    
    game_is_on = True
    while game_is_on:
        screen.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        snake.move()
    
        if snake.head.distance(food) < 15:
            food.refresh()
            snake.extend()
            score.increse_score()
        if snake.head.xcor()>280 or snake.head.xcor() < -280 or snake.head.ycor()>280 or snake.head.ycor()<-280:
            game_is_on=False
            score.over()
    
    
    
    
    
    screen.exitonclick()
```

**Score.py**

```
from turtle import Turtle
class Score(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        self.hideturtle()
        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0,250)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.write(f"score:{self.score}", align="center",font=("Ariel",24,"normal"))

    def over(self):
        self.goto(0,0)
        self.write(f"GAME OVER", align="center",font=("Ariel",24,"normal"))

    def increse_score(self):
        self.score+=1
        self.clear()
        self.update()
```

**Snake.py**

```
from turtle import Turtle,Screen
screen=Screen()
START_POSI = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DIS=20
UP=90
DOWN=270
LEFT=180
RIGHT=0
class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segment=[]
        self.create_snake()
        self.head=self.segment[0]


    def create_snake(self):
        for position in START_POSI:
            self.add_segment(position)

    def add_segment(self, position):
        new_segment = Turtle("square")
        new_segment.color("white")
        new_segment.penup()
        new_segment.goto(position)
        self.segment.append(new_segment)

    def extend(self):
        self.add_segment(self.segment[-1].position())
        
    def move(self):
        for seg in range(len(START_POSI) - 1, 0, -1):
            new_x = self.segment[seg - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segment[seg - 1].ycor()
            self.segment[seg].goto(new_x, new_y)
        self.segment[0].forward(MOVE_DIS)

    def up(self):
        if self.head.heading()!=DOWN:
            self.head.setheading(UP)

    def down(self):
        if self.head.heading()!=UP:
            self.head.setheading(DOWN)

    def left(self):
        if self.head.heading()!=RIGHT:
            self.head.setheading(LEFT)

    def right(self):
        if self.head.heading()!=LEFT:
            self.head.setheading(RIGHT)
```

**food.py**

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random
class Food(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.penup()
        self.shape("circle")
        self.shapesize(0.5,0.5)
        self.color("red")
        self.refresh()
    def refresh(self):
        xcord = random.randint(-280,280)
        ycord = random.randint(-280, 280)
        self.goto(xcord,ycord)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only looping as far as `len(START_POSI)` but this isn't the entire tail after extension. Try `len(self.segment)`:

```py
    def move(self):
        #                    v----------- here's the fix
        for seg in range(len(self.segment) - 1, 0, -1):
            new_x = self.segment[seg - 1].xcor()
```

As an aside, I'd call `turtle.update()` and `time.sleep()` (in that order) at the very bottom of the update loop, not at the top. The per-frame flow is `update state/positions -> redraw -> register a tick/repaint/update with the turtle API -> sleep for the next frame`. I ususally use `ontimer` rather than `while` and `sleep` but I'm not sure that it's necessarily much more reliable (that's a pending research project).

Also, I'm [not a fan of subclassing Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352). Although this program appears OK at a glance, the practice can lead to a number of issues down the line so I'd switch to composition rather than inheritance. Only subclass your own interfaces or APIs which are explicitly designed for it.