# Turtle Object does not move to new position goto(x, y)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Good morning,

I have created a turtle object (a paddle) which I intent to move from left to right from a predetermine position. I am using the turtle.goto(x, y) to achieve this however it is not working. I have added a print statement in the functions go_left / go_right, just to see if the code was working and yes the new x position is being set but the paddle does not move.  I have not a clue on why this is happening. Any Ideas ?. Thanks for the help.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('Testing Paddle')
screen.tracer(0)

# Creating a paddle shape and registering it to the turtle shape custom list
screen.register_shape("paddle", ((0, 0), (15, 0), (15, 80), (0, 80)))

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('paddle')
        self.color('magenta')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def go_left(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() - 20
        self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())
        print(new_x, self.ycor())

    def go_right(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() + 20
        self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())
        print(new_x, self.ycor())

paddle = Paddle((-40, -240))
screen.listen()

game_is_on = True

screen.onkey(fun=paddle.go_left, key='Left')
screen.onkey(fun=paddle.go_right, key='Right')

screen.update()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tip: [don't subclass turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441331/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-python-that-is-inherited-from-turtle-module/71003069#71003069). Example: [real time turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics/70979967#70979967) for handling keypresses and continuous movement (don't change positions in handlers and run your own update loop).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind several key presses together in turtle graphics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879608/how-to-bind-several-key-presses-together-in-turtle-graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set

```
screen.tracer(0)
```

so now it doesn't update screen automatically and you have to do it on your own.

You have to use

```
screen.update()
```

after changing position. (After every `goto()`, etc.)

---

**EDIT:**

`Turtle` has one problem: after pressing key system makes longer delay before it starts treats it as repeated press - and paddle moves with some delay after pressing button. This need different method to work with keys. It needs to use `onkeypress` to increase speed (without moving paddle) and `onkeyrelease` to decrease speed. And code has to use `ontimer` to repeat code which will check current speed and move paddel.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('Testing Paddle')
screen.tracer(0)

# Creating a paddle shape and registering it to the turtle shape custom list
screen.register_shape("paddle", ((0, 0), (15, 0), (15, 80), (0, 80)))

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position, color='magenta'):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('paddle')
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)
        self.speed = 0
        
    def on_press_left(self):
        self.speed -= 20
        
    def on_press_right(self):
        self.speed += 20

    def on_release_left(self):
        self.speed += 20
        
    def on_release_right(self):
        self.speed -= 20

    def update(self):
        if self.speed != 0:
            new_x = self.xcor() + self.speed
            
            # pad width: 80
            
            if new_x < -300:
                new_x = -300
            if new_x > 300 - 80:  
                new_x = 300 - 80
                
            self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())

# ---

def update():
    enemy.speed = -paddle.speed  # moves enemy in different direction
    
    paddle.update()
    enemy.update()
    
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(fun=update, t=25)  # repeat after 25ms (0.025s)

# --- main ---

game_is_on = True

paddle = Paddle((-40, -240))
enemy  = Paddle((-40, 240+15), 'red')
screen.listen()

screen.onkeypress(fun=paddle.on_press_left, key='Left')
screen.onkeypress(fun=paddle.on_press_right, key='Right')

screen.onkeyrelease(fun=paddle.on_release_left, key='Left')
screen.onkeyrelease(fun=paddle.on_release_right, key='Right')

screen.ontimer(fun=update, t=25)  # execute after 25ms (0.025s)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, I have added in my original code a screen.update() statement after the statements for moving the paddle position, yet it does not work. Removing screen.tracer() does not affect the outcome.

Comment: where did change code? I don't see `screen.update()` after `goto()`. And when I remove `screen.tracer()` then it works even without `screen.update()` after `goto()` - but it may need to change key repeating setting in settings - or it need different method to work with keys. `on_press` may need only to set variable with direction and you may need loop which will check direction and move paddle.

Comment: I added differnt code which use `onkeypress` to increase `speed` and `onkeyrelease` to decrease `speed`, and `ontimer` to check speed and move paddle.

Comment: Furas, Thanks very much for your answer.  in re-wrote the code again and somehow it worked. I noticed that this time I did not write the screen.tracer(0)  as you suggested and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your screen too to show the turtle's new position

add this line in the last line of the functions `screen.update()`

#### Modified Code.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('Testing Paddle')
screen.tracer(0)

# Creating a paddle shape and registering it to the turtle shape custom list
screen.register_shape("paddle", ((0, 0), (15, 0), (15, 80), (0, 80)))

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('paddle')
        self.color('magenta')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)

    def go_left(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() - 20
        self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())
        print(new_x, self.ycor())
        screen.update() # edit


    def go_right(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() + 20
        self.goto(new_x, self.ycor())
        print(new_x, self.ycor())
        screen.update() # edit

paddle = Paddle((-40, -240))
screen.listen()

game_is_on = True

screen.onkey(fun=paddle.go_left, key='Left')
screen.onkey(fun=paddle.go_right, key='Right')

screen.update()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you check my code, the statement screen.update() is at the bottom of the code but it does not do the trick.