# How can I use class inheritance properly to create a Turtle with a custom shape?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I've been trying to use the `super()` command in my class but it isn't working. Here is the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen=Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor("black")

class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("circle")
food=Food()
screen.exitonclick()
```

I'm trying to get the shape to be a circle but that isn't working and all I can see is the default arrow shape. I also tried `.color`, `.forward` and none seem to work.

Comment: What's not working? From an inheritance perspective, nothing is wrong with this code. Are you creating an *instance* of `Food` that will draw itself?

Comment: This should work fine -- can you share the rest of the code (where you actually create the turtle and see what it looks like)?

Comment: When i use food=Food() it doesn't work , I've already setup the screen but in the middle its still a default arrow even when i use self.forward in the class setting it doesn't seems to do anything

Comment: I created a small test program with your `Food` class and it does indeed show a circle-shaped turtle on the screen.  Please update your question with the *exact* code you're running.

Comment: @samwise besides the class setup the full code will be just food= Food() , I've already setup the screen class and it works just fine ( tested another turtle on it and it works fine)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you are actually doing.

Comment: @samwise yes this is indeed the issue im having that my code is written well but doesn't seems to work for me , is it a problem from my end , im using pycharm and the code I've written is from a tutorial, but it just doesn't seem to work for me any idea why ?

Comment: I updated the question with the full code

Comment: Your "full code" example does not have `food = Food()` (even though earlier you said you tried that), so it's hard for us to know what is the actual code you're using...

Comment: Yes sorry I just updated it , this is 100% the full code sorry about earlier

Comment: So any idea why it isn't working because i do believe that the class is written well but i dont know why it isn't working for me but works for anyone else

Comment: I think the `Screen` stuff is the problem.  When I tested your code I just created a `Food()` and then called `mainloop()`, and that worked fine.  With your `Screen` code I don't see any turtle at all; I'm not familiar enough with the turtle module to know how exactly you're supposed to use that class.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help I'll see what i can do from my end

Comment: The problem may be that shapes are drawn in black by default, and so setting the background color to black makes the shape invisible.  Try setting the foreground color to white.  (Or don't set the background color to black.)

Comment: Yep still doesn't work i even made a fresh new code with just screen=Screen() and exit on click, i still see the default arrow shape, it probably something to do with pycharm and not the actual code because i did try everything

Comment: [I would avoid inheritance in turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441331/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-python-that-is-inherited-from-turtle-module/71003069#71003069). `Turtle`s are not meant to be subclassed; they're magical, auto-rendering, ungarbage-collectable entities with over 150 properties with common names that should be kept at arm's length. Prefer composition over inheritance. That said, the code works fine for me once I remove the black background.

Answer (score 0):

whatever the question is trying to achieve, the default colour is black. So you could change the colour in the class like this:

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen=Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor("black")

class Food(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("circle")
        self.color('red')   # <-- add a colour

food=Food()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Which will then give this:

[image]

So you now have a red circle.