# How can I get current angle of an object in turtle library of Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying use tiltangle, hovewer I cannot understand how it works exactly. Everytime I run following code, it gives 122.0, I do not know how can I deal with it:

```
def collide(self):
    initial_angle = self.tiltangle()
    self.right(initial_angle + 90)
```

How can I get angle of an object in turtle library of Python?

Comment: Please add a link to "turtle library of python" and full code which would run if copy pasted [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Because now it not clear what `def collide(self):` and `self.tiltangle()` means

Comment: What is not clear from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.tiltangle): *"return the current tilt-angle, i. e. the angle between the orientation of the turtleshape and the heading of the turtle (its direction of movement)."*?

Comment: If you're subclassing `Turtle`, I suggest [not doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352). But please share a [mcve] so we have full context for what you're doing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).

Let's take the following description.

> Imagine a robotic turtle starting at (0, 0) in the x-y plane. After an import turtle, give it the command turtle.forward(15), and it moves (on-screen!) 15 pixels in the direction it is facing, drawing a line as it moves. Give it the command turtle.right(25), and it rotates in-place 25 degrees clockwise.

That means, if you get the value of 122.0 every single time, it is because your `initial_angle` value is 32.0.

So, the value changes depending on the side of an angle. If you change the script like:

```
self.left(initial_angle + 90)
```

Then, you would get the value of 58.0.

Answer (score 0):

You want `heading()`, not `tiltangle()`.  The `heading()` method gives you the direction that the turtle is currently facing, which you can change with `left()`, `right()`, or `setheading()`.

The `tiltangle()` method is for changing the visual appearance of the cursor, not its actual heading on the screen.  For example, in a *Space Invaders* style game, I've used the turtle-shaped cursor with a heading of 0 (zero) degrees so I can use `forward()` and `backward()` to move it on the screen.  But I want the turtle image itself to point upward towards the invaders.  So, I set it's `tiltangle()` to 90 so it's facing upward but moving left and right.

```
def collide(self):
    initial_angle = self.heading()
    self.right(initial_angle + 90)
```

is the same as:

```
def collide(self):
    self.right(90)
```

As noted in the documentation, `tiltangle()` is "the angle between the orientation of the turtleshape and the heading of the turtle (its direction of movement)"