# Paddles on my Pong game do not move after pressing the keys on Python 3.11 Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, pong, python-3.11

Main.py:

```py
from turtle import Screen
from Paddle import Paddle

#creating screen
screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(1000, 600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('Pong')
screen.tracer(0)

#paddle objects: rPaddle is for the paddle in the right and lPaddle for the left one
rPaddle = Paddle((350, 0))     #the tuple is for the starting position of the paddle object
lPaddle = Paddle((-350, 0))

#screen listeners
screen.listen()
screen.onkey(lPaddle.up, 'w')
screen.onkey(lPaddle.down, 's')
screen.onkey(rPaddle.up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(rPaddle.down, 'Down')

game_on = True
while game_on:
    screen.update()


screen.exitonclick()
```

Paddle.py:

```py
from turtle import Turtle


class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self, starting_coords): #creates the paddles
        super().__init__()
        self.paddle = Turtle("square")
        self.paddle.color('white')
        self.paddle.shapesize(5, 1)
        self.paddle.penup()
        self.paddle.goto(starting_coords)

    def up(self):
        new_y = self.paddle.ycor() + 40 #makes the paddle move 40 pixels up
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
        print("up")

    def down(self):
        new_y = self.paddle.ycor() - 40 # moves the paddle 40 pixels down
        self.goto(self.xcor(), new_y)
        print('down')
```

I left some print statements to make sure the key is being pressed, but still the paddle would not move even if it shows the print statements, so I am very confused about what to do as I am following a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you're subclassing Turtle and also composing a Turtle instance as a field of the class. This seems to have created confusion: you're displaying `self.paddle` on the screen, then using `self.goto()` to move. `self` is a totally different, invisible turtle! You probably mean: `self.paddle.goto()`, which moves the composed turtle rather than the inherited turtle that's implicitly created when you subclass.

Remove `Turtle` from `class Paddle(Turtle):` and remove `super().__init__()` to get rid of the invisible turtle and display a clear error if you accidentally mix up calls.

A useful way to debug this is `turtle.turtles()` method, which returns a list of all turtles that have been created, from the perspective of the `turtle` module. After your `Paddle` instantiations, run:

```py
rPaddle = Paddle((350, 0))  # creates 2 Turtles
lPaddle = Paddle((-350, 0))  # creates 2 more Turtles
import turtle
print(turtle.turtles())
```

You'll see:

```
[
  <__main__.Paddle object at 0x7f9da4803ac0>,
  <turtle.Turtle object at 0x7f9da4802590>,
  <__main__.Paddle object at 0x7f9da48039d0>,
  <turtle.Turtle object at 0x7f9da4801690>
]
```

4 turtles--what?!

See [How to create a subclass in python that is inherited from turtle Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441331/how-to-create-a-subclass-in-python-that-is-inherited-from-turtle-module/71003069#71003069) for more reasons why you shouldn't subclass turtle, if this isn't evidence enough.

---

As an aside, `while game_on:` slams the CPU as hard as possible, giving a non-portable framerate--fast machines run fast, slow machines run slow. It's better to use `ontimer` to run the event loop. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979967/6243352).

This is what the CPU looks like on my machine running your code (Xwayland is handling the Tkinter turtle window blasting away, causing my fan to turn on):

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   3779 greg      20   0 1002612 113320  69604 R  90.0   0.3   3:48.13 Xwayland 
  15515 greg      20   0   41948  20736  11136 S  25.0   0.1   0:29.43 python3  
  11275 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   5.0   0.0   0:01.38 kworker+
```

Running the `ontimer` example from the link:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
   2974 greg      20   0 6573268 327136 174848 S   7.0   1.0   2:52.85 gnome-s+ 
   5867 greg      20   0 2616860 164488  98768 S   4.3   0.5   1:34.06 Isolate+ 
   3779 greg      20   0  997208 113320  69604 S   3.3   0.3   4:15.45 Xwayland 
  15726 greg      20   0   41992  20604  11392 S   2.7   0.1   0:00.40 python3
```

Less work, more stable framerate.