# Python - moving turtle on the y-axis acting weird after 'if' statement

Tags: python, if-statement, graphics, turtle-graphics, pong

I am doing a Pong game, following an online Python course and I have encountered a unsolvable problem with Turtle. I have checked the code several times but it appears just as it is in the course assignment but on my end the results are different.

I am making a class about the ball:

```
from turtle import Turtle


class Ball(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape('circle')
        self.color('white')
        self.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)
        self.penup()
        self.x_move = 10
        self.y_move = 10

    def move(self):
        new_x = self.xcor() + self.x_move
        new_y = self.xcor() + self.y_move
        self.goto(new_x, new_y)

    def bounce_y(self):
        self.y_move *= -1

    def bounce_3(self):
        self.x_move *= -1
```

And then in the main.py I am making a wall collision detection using the following:

```
    if ball.ycor() > 280 or ball.ycor() < -280:
        ball.bounce_y()
```

Technically, this should result in the ball bouncing off the top end of the screen but in reality it starts doing zig-zag movements as the ycor are changing from -10 to +30 and then -10 and +30 again, until I stop the program:

```
y: 240.0
y: 250.0
y: 260.0
y: 270.0
y: 280.0
y: 290.0
y: 280.0
y: 290.0
y: 320.0
y: 310.0
y: 340.0
y: 330.0
y: 360.0
y: 350.0
y: 380.0
y: 370.0
y: 400.0
y: 390.0
y: 420.0
y: 410.0
y: 440.0
y: 430.0
y: 460.0
y: 450.0
```

I have checked my code several times but I really have no idea where's the problem so I will appreciate any hints and ideas where to look for a mistake.

Comment: Please share main.py (a complete, runnable [mcve]). Thanks. Many courses recommend poor-practice event loops or window sizes that may be unreliable on different machines. Generally, collision resolution involves more than just changing direction--it involves pushing the ball out of the wall. BTW, I would [discourage subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352). It causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: `new_y = self.xcor() + self.y_move` Shouldn't there be `self.ycor()`?

Comment: Does `bounce_3` imply you have `bounce_2` and `bounce_1` as well (possibly others)?

Comment: @RobertHacken - Thanks for the tip! :) This was the problem. I don't know how I missed that... Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine for a moment that your ball somehow reaches the value 300 (which is a forbidden zone for the ball).

It will bounce and then go back 10 pixels to 290, but 290 > 280 so it will bounce again and go up to 300. It will always get stuck bouncing.

What you need to do not only check the position the ball is, but also the direction of the ball. If the ball is too high but is already descending, do not bounce it (same if it's too low but already ascending)

```
if ball.ycor() > 280 and ball.y_move > 0:
    ball.bounce_y()
elif ball.ycor() < -280 and ball.y_move < 0:
    ball.bounce_y()
```

Also instead of first moving the ball to a potentially invalid position and then bouncing it, you should probably first check if the target position is valid, and bounce it before reaching such invalid position.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It is logical but unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue. It turned out that it's just a typo on my end when I was defining the move method.

Comment: Well it does solve the issue. If you just correct the typo but you don't implement the suggestions I gave, then if the ball ever enters deep in the forbidden zone it will be forever stuck in it.

Comment: After I changed the typo, I haven't experienced problems. If some occur, I will add your suggestion as well.

Comment: Ok, waiting for the program to crash instead of solving a known bus is a "good "decision.

Comment: @Elerium115 I don't think there's any point in trying to make a program work in a state it shouldn't be in in the first place. It may be a good thing to be paranoid about user input but definitely not about the algorithm you should be in full control of.