# TypeError on Trinket Implementation of Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The code below works fine on Windows 10 with Python 3.10. When you click on the turtle, its color changes. However when I run the code in the browser-based Trinket environment, here: https://trinket.io/python/0da2ab1181, I get the following error:

```
ExternalError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'constructor') on line 15 in main.py
```

when I click on the Turtle.

How can I make this work correctly please? I've looked at the docs for the module and they give:

```
Help on function fillcolor in turtle:

turtle.fillcolor = fillcolor(*args)
    Return or set the fillcolor.
    
    Arguments:
    Four input formats are allowed:
      - fillcolor()
        Return the current fillcolor as color specification string,
        possibly in hex-number format (see example).
        May be used as input to another color/pencolor/fillcolor call.
      - fillcolor(colorstring)
        s is a Tk color specification string, such as "red" or "yellow"
      - fillcolor((r, g, b))
        *a tuple* of r, g, and b, which represent, an RGB color,
        and each of r, g, and b are in the range 0..colormode,
        where colormode is either 1.0 or 255
      - fillcolor(r, g, b)
        r, g, and b represent an RGB color, and each of r, g, and b
        are in the range 0..colormode
    
    If turtleshape is a polygon, the interior of that polygon is drawn
    with the newly set fillcolor.
    
    Example:
    >>> fillcolor('violet')
    >>> col = pencolor()
    >>> fillcolor(col)
    >>> fillcolor(0, .5, 0)
```

Programs code:

```
class ToggleTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.color1 = "red"
        self.color2 = "blue"
        self.fillcolor(self.color1)
        self.onclick(self.toggle_color)

    def toggle_color(self, x, y):
        if self.fillcolor() == self.color1:
            self.fillcolor(self.color2)
        else:
            self.fillcolor(self.color1)


tt = ToggleTurtle()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Trinket's version of `turtle`.  I'm pretty sure they're not using the standard Python version of that module (which would be rather difficult to make appear on a web page), and their reimplementation doesn't seem to properly handle calling `.fillcolor()` with no parameter.  The word-around would be to have your own variable (`self.color`, perhaps) to keep track of the current color, making sure to update it every time you call `.fillcolor()`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd [avoid subclassing turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this trinket.io turtle library, functions like `fillcolor()` are `pencolor()` are only *setters*, not both setters *and getters* like in the standard Python turtle library.  So, as @jasonharper suggests (+1), we need to keep track of the color state explicitly:

```
class ToggleTurtle(turtle.Turtle):
    COLOR_1 = "red"
    COLOR_2 = "blue"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")

        self.current_color = self.COLOR_1
        self.fillcolor(self.current_color)

        self.onclick(self.toggle_color)

    def toggle_color(self, x, y):
        if self.current_color == self.COLOR_1:
            self.current_color = self.COLOR_2
        else:
            self.current_color = self.COLOR_1

        self.fillcolor(self.current_color)
```